# Django serializing Queryset with related entity fields

Tags: python, django, json

I'm trying to join 2 entities, get specific fields from them, and return a JSON of that.
I tried writing the following code:

```
import datetime
result = Foo.objects.all()
result = result.select_related('bar').extra(select={'bar_has_address':'IF(bar.has_address = '',0,1)'})
result = result.filter(time__gte=datetime.date.today())
return HttpResponse(serializers.serialize('json', result),mimetype="application/json")
```

Now I'm only getting a json containing the fields of Foo, whereas I want to get Bar's fields as well, ideally the returned JSON would have specific fields from both entities:

```
[{
    'name': 'lorem ipsum', //from Foo
    'has_address': 1, //from Bar
    'address': 'some address', //from Bar
    'id': 1, //from Foo
},... ]
```

even under `result.values('...')` I'm not getting any of Bar's fields 
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, django built-in serializers cannot work with model related fields. Take a look at:

- [DjangoFullSerializers](https://code.google.com/p/wadofstuff/wiki/DjangoFullSerializers)
- this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14753889/771848) and suggested serializer
- relevant [open ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/4656) in django issue tracker

Also see:

- [Django serialization of inherited model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132980/django-serialization-of-inherited-model)
- [Serialize django models with reverse One-To-One fields to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164604/serialize-django-models-with-reverse-one-to-one-fields-to-json?rq=1)

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'll give Fullserializers a try, see if it solves my problem, it's not really intuitive if by default it ignores the select_related & extra

Comment: @Asaf did you give serializers a try? :) Should I remove the answer or you can mark it as accepted to resolve the topic? Thanks.