# django - values() for foreign key relations

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

Django values() is very handy, is it possible to serialize nested object too?

```
class Book(model.Models):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

I would hope to do something like

```
d = Book.objects.all().values('name', 'user', deep={
    'user': ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name'] # related user fields
})
```

And to get a result

```
[
 {
  'name': 'book1',
  'user': {'username': 'user1', 'first_name': '...', 'last_name': '..'}
 }
]
```

So I'll get a nested dict for the foreign key object (user), instead of just the user id.
I don't need more than a depth of 1, so only one level of related objects.

Comment: Django built-in serializers don't support related fields but there are some alternatives available: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17032362/django-serializing-queryset-with-related-entity-fields/17032984#17032984

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest [Django RestFrameWork](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) for efficient use. Define your `serializers.py` as below,

```
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer


class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name')


class BookSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('name', 'user')
```

and try this in your view/shell

```
book = Book.objects.get(id=1)
result = BookSerializer(book).data
```

OR

```
all_book_objects = Book.objects.all()
result = BookSerializer(all_book_objects, many=True).data
```